# New text object for LaTeX subscript or superscript

Tags: filetype-tex, custom-text-object

Suppose in a latex file, I have a line

```
$X_{i_{j}}$ and $Y^{i_{k}}$
```

My goal is to define a text object in VIM for the subscript, i.e. `_{i_{j}}`, and superscript, i.e. `^{i_{k}}`.

I was reading this [wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects). It requires more knowledge about command-line mode than I currently have.

For subscript, I was thinking the ex command should start by finding `_`, then move the cursor to its immediately right, and finally find the paired brace using `%` in normal model. I do not know how to write this up in ex command.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [vim-text-object](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) it is a plugin which allows you to easily define custom text objects.